# .net HttpClient post api response not rendering properly

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to get the html content from the news site `https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-article/2/News`, 
with the Http `Post` Request.

However in the response, page is returning the Unicode characters.

I am obstructed in converting the Unicode characters to html.

**URL**:

```
var nayapatrika = await ApiClient.PostAsync("https://nayapatrikadaily.com/ajax/pagination.php");
```

**PostAsync:**

```
public static async Task<HtmlDocument> PostAsync(string uri)
{
    string responseJson = string.Empty;
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        var values = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("perPage", "20"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("page", "2"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cat", "1"),
        };

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
        }

        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(responseJson);
        }
    }

    return htmlDocument;
}
```

On response the page is always returning with the below characters.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserializing the api response did the trick for me. As i noticed the responses it has two attributes: `newsList` and `numPages`.

I created the class: `ResponseObj`

```
public class ResponseObj
{
    public string numPage { get; set; }
    public string newsList { get; set; }
}
```

and deserliazed into `ResponseObj`

`var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObj>(responseJson);`

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{


    responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObj>(responseJson);

    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(obj.newsList);
}
```